# Symfony form inheritance : Neither the property nor one of the methods exist

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a nested form

```
demand
    home
       child
       godfather
```

`demand` is a parent and embed `home` which embed `child` and `father` (2 last forms are on the same level)

In `DemandeType` I have:

```
           $builder
           ->add('date', 'datetype')
           ->add('name', 'text')
           //...

           ->add('home', 'home', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Home',
            'inherit_data' => true
             ))

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Demand',
    ));
}
```

In `HomeType` :

```
           $builder
           ->add('address', 'textarea')
           //...

           ->add('child', 'child', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Child',
            'inherit_data' => true
             ))

           ->add('godfather', 'godfather', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Godfather',
            'inherit_data' => true
             ))

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Home',
    ));
}
```

And in `ChildType` and `GodfatherType` I have only text fields for firstname, lastname with their right data_class.

But when I submit the form (DemandType, wichh embed all subforms) I got this error :

> Neither the property "address" nor one of the methods "getAddress()", "address()", "isAddress()", "hasAddress()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Demand".

And these methods don't belong to `Demand` entity but `Home` entity. I've put the `inherit_data`, what I'm missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you're using `inherit_data`. This property makes the form pass the entire submitted data to its child instead of a single property (or anything from getter function) which happens by default.

You do this for both `demand` and `home` so that's why `home` form type receives an instance `Demand` entity. So I guess you want to remove `inherit_data` from `home` and use just:

```
->add('home', 'home', array(
    'mapped' => false,
    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Home',
))
```

In this case `home` will receive data from `$demand->getHome()` which should be a `Hone` entity.

I'm not sure you really need to use `inherit_data` at all but depends on your use case. Usually, you don't need it because you have structure of entities such as:

```
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class Demand {
    /** @ORM\OneToWhatever() */
    private $home;
    public function getHome() {
        return $this->home;
    }
}

/** @ORM\Entity() */
class Home {
    /** @ORM\OneToWhatever() */
    private $child;
    public function getChild() {
        return $this->child;
    }
}

/** @ORM\Entity() */
class Child { ... }
```

But I don't know what exactly your data structure is so it's hard to help.

Also, you're using `mapped => false` which I'm not sure is what you want because it prevent Symfony from updating entities with form data.

See:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#inherit-data