# How to render only a specific grandchild in embedded forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

My question is similar to [Symfony form inheritance : Neither the property nor one of the methods exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39431263/390177) but there are no templates included.

I have a nested form

```
demand
    home
       n children
```

DemandType

```
class DemandTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension {
    public function buildForm(...): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('home', HomeType::class, [
            ]);
```

HomeType

```
class HomeType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(): void {
        $builder
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ChildrenType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'label' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Home::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

ChildrenType

```
class ChildrenType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(...): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Children::class,
        ]);
    }
```

My form

```
{{ form_widget(form.children) }}
```

> Neither the property "children" nor one of the methods "children()", "getchildren()"/"ischildren()"/"haschildren()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

It seems I have to render the home input.

Is there no possibility to render only the children input? Perhaps with some special context (pseudo code)?

```
{% block form_context(form.home) %}
     {{ form_widget(form.children) }}
{% endblock form_context %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Assuming `form` in your twig example is an instance of `DemandType`, then you would do:

```
{{ form_widget(form.home.children) }}
```

However, this may not work because `children` is also a built in property on some Symfony form types. In `HomeType` I would rename the field `children` to something else, such as `childrenCollection`, in which case you would do this in your twig view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.home.childrenCollection) }}
```